# if a small tree dies and is removed will the roots left behind cause the soil to bulge up into a mound 2 feet high and 20 foot across

Tags: trees

a tree died was then blown down by a storm the council removed it to ground level
slowly a mound has grown near by some 2 foot high 20 foot in diameter and is still spreading sideways which the council say is just the roots rotting in the soil also all the grass around and on the mound stay green even with the current heatwave all other grass is brown

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you in the UK? If you are not, what do you mean by 'council'?

Comment: Rotting stumps cause the ground to sink, not swell, because the volume of woody material under the soil decreases as it decomposes. Large roots can also cause the ground to sink near where the stump was, but roots "out into the yard" rarely cause any issues. I think that there is something else going on there, especially with the area remaining moist during the heatwave. Possibly a slow leak from a water lateral line into a house caused, perhaps, by whomever the council hired to remove the tree?

Comment: The national forest is behind my house. When I walk in it I avoid the pits where trees have died, roots rotted and made a hole.  Living pine trees are the opposite , making a one foot mound around the tree base ( mostly  chips of bark) .

Answer (score 2):

I look forward to an update when the actual cause comes to light, because that explanation is Male Bovine Byproduct by a shorter name.

Tree roots rot, rather slowly, and shrink. They do not swell while slowly rotting, they do not rot at high speed, and they do not water the grass above them.

A combination of an expansive clay soil and a waterline break would be my best guess, as I can't see the mound happening just from a water leak in normal soils (which would get wet, but not swell.) But it is a guess.

Comment: If this isn't a water leak, something rising 2 feet instead of gradually subsiding sounds more than a bit creepy.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of 3 reasons why this might happen:

1. The OP says the tree was blown down. Did it snap off cleanly at the base? If not then a large amount of physical stress would be applied to the root system. When shallowly rooted as with trees on thin soil this often means the flat disc of the root is torn out immediately and appears as perhaps a near vertical semicircle of root volume with soil attached with the other half of the root volume remaining in the ground folded under the trunk which is now lying down. When the root volume does not come out immediately there can be enough stress that roots slowly twist and break over time as forces get resolved. The more roots break the more quickly the tensions can be resolved and a mound appears over time.
2. Some trees react vigorously to having their tops cut off. There can be a lot of shoot growth from the root volume and this might occur quite suddenly tending to push soil up at the surface as new vegetative growth expresses itself. If this is so then shoots should start appearing fairly soon.
3. The weirdest explanation would be that while liquids and solids do not expand, water under pressure and gases can expand and do make soil burst up. I don't know why gases would develop underground; perhaps some preexisting condition was exacerbated by the blow over. If water is involved then tapping a tube into the root area and then removing a core should reveal a water level close to the soil surface.

Comment: Three convincing explanations. @3. Rot develops gases like carbon dioxide (aerobic conditions) and methane (anaerobic conditions). For the latter see for instance https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10533-019-00600-6 or https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Methane-emissions-from-heartwood-rot-in-temperate-forests-worldwide_tbl4_261133195